# How Do They Get BTC Wallet.dat With Balance?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, bitcoind, wallet, wallet.dat

Going through YouTube, I found some videos on Bitcoin  wallet.dat with balance.

Looking at these videos, you will notice that these balances found in these btc  wallet.dat are not on watch only address. The balances are in the main btc  address.

I have searched google on how these YouTubers got these btc  wallet.dat with balance but i found nothing. So i decided to post my question here.

I know bitcoin is unhackable for now.

Is this wallet.dat with balance some sort of scam or exploit?

How Do They Get BTC Wallet.dat With Balance?

Your answer will be highly appreciated

YOUTUBE VIDEOS LINK

[Selling wallet.dat Bitcoin Core balance 340 btc. Sale or buy wallet.dat wallet-dat.net](https://youtube.com/watch?v=uTux0LNY8UU)

Comment: It’s a scam, just ignore it

Answer (score 2):

> Is this wallet.dat with balance some sort of scam or exploit?

It looks like a scam.

There is *never* a good reason to buy a wallet.dat.

> Looking at these videos, you will notice

I guess we will notice whatever the video creator tricks us into noticing. As I'm sure you know, making an app that looks like another app is trivial. As is editing video to make the unreal look real. A Bitcoin wallet that genuinely contains $100k now may contain $0 one microsecond later. Even a genuine photo of a leather wallet with genuine $100 banknotes sticking out of it is not proof that the wallet will still have those contents when a buyer receives it.

Answer (score 0):

I am the one who made the video, and the video is a real wallet, but the password is lost forever, as everyone knows in Bitcoin core, passwords can be brute-force an unlimited number of times. The video is not fake, I can show any person any wallet in real time, as well as any evidence. The video contains the address of the site and you can see for yourself, there are also wallets on the site for free download with a balance, but with a forgotten password. the site also has empty wallets, these are wallets that were hacked and all bitcoins were withdrawn